# PostgreSQL pagination along with row number indexing

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

Okay, so I am working on query porting of an **oracle DB** to postgres. My query needs to give me numbered records, along with pagination.

Consider the following oracle code:

```
select * from (
    select RS.*, ROWNUM as RN from ( 
        select * from STUDENTS order by GRADES
    ) RS where ROWNUM <= (#{startIndex} + #{pageSize}) 
) where RN > #{startIndex}
```

Notice that there are 2 uses of `ROWNUM` here:

1. To provide a row number to each row in query result.
2. For pagination.

I need to **port such a query to postgres**.

I know how to paginate using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` commands for pagination, but I am not able to provide a global row number (each row in query result gets a unique row number).

On the other hand, I was able to find `ROW_NUMBER()` command which can provide me with the global row numbers, but it is not reccommended for pagination purposes, since the number of tuples in my DB are very large.

**How do I write a similar code in postgres?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution looks much simpler in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *,
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY grades, id) AS rn
FROM students
ORDER BY grades, id
OFFSET $1 LIMIT $2;
```

Here, `id` stands for the primary key and is used to disambiguate between equal `grades`.

That query is efficient if there is an index on `grades` and the offset is not too high:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)
SELECT *,
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY grades, id) AS rn
FROM students
ORDER BY grades, id
OFFSET 10 LIMIT 20;

                             QUERY PLAN                                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.01..2.49 rows=20 width=20)
        (actual time=0.204..0.365 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.28..74.25 rows=1000 width=20)
                  (actual time=0.109..0.334 rows=30 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using students_grades_idx on students
                        (cost=0.28..59.25 rows=1000 width=12)
                        (actual time=0.085..0.204 rows=30 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.515 ms
 Execution time: 0.627 ms
(5 rows)
```

Observe the `actual` values in the plan.

Pagination with `OFFSET` is *always* inefficient with large offsets; consider [keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

Comment: So if I have a large number of records, I should not use `OFFSET` ? Can you provide with the keyset version of the same query?

Comment: No, that exceeds the scope of the answer. Read the information at the link I posted. Using offsets should be avoided if possible, in PostgreSQL as well as in Oracle.

Comment: why not order by rn? or even grades, rn? just dont quite understand how this works... also will the row number assigned stable between different executions?

Comment: We do effectively order by `rn`, because that is ordered by `grades`. You are right, the row number is unstable. To avoid that, append the primary key to both `ORDER BY` clauses. I have fixed the answer.